# Why is my data converted to character when I create a time series?

Tags: r, time-series, character

I am currently trying to run an adf.test to check whether the variables in my time series are stationary or non-stationary. However, when I create my time series data,

```
datnew<-cbind(Date,Temp,GHG,SOX,SOL)
datts<-ts(datnew,start = 1850, end = 2011, frequency = 1)
```

all of my numeric values become character values, and these become impossible to work with. I tried to convert my table to a data frame with both as.data.frame and as.data.frame.matrix, but this function returns only integer values when I create the time series. If anyone knows why this is, or can help me with a workaround I would really appreciate it.

Comment: dont use `cbind`? use `data.frame` straight away? cbind prob turned all your 4 vectors into the same data type class

Comment: No. When you call `cbind` by itself on vectors, it uses `base::cbind`, which creates a `matrix`. A matrix is always a single class, so if any one of your variables is `character`, then they are all converted. If instead you called `cbind.data.frame` (which is called automatically if the first argument is already a `data.frame`) or `data.frame` (as suggested), then you would not have them converted. However, you will still get `factor`s for your textual vectors, so I suggest including `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Chinsoon has the answer. `cbind` converts everything to the same type. It's also (for type dataframe) a wrapper for `data.frame` function. So just use `data.frame`.